# What is the simplest yet complete question to assess whether or not a person has a strong skill in plain TeX?

Tags: plain-tex

If I have to hire a person for doing a plain TeX related jobs, what question should I ask to the person? I want the question to be as simple as possible and it has to accommodate the maximum number of available aspects.

Comment: question: _what are the design errors done by Knuth in his elaboration of the typesetting system known as `TeX`_?

Comment: @jfbu: And what is the answer?

Comment: I am not looking for a job.

Comment: ... but I would say for example the absence of hooks into paragraph building, for example the impossibility to know what is the depth of the material in  the current line before the current point.

Comment: With multiple compilation it will still be impossible know the depth as well?

Comment: without additional mark-up? well, I feel the pressure here that perhaps I should have thought more than ten seconds, but a priori, I don't see how  one can just insert some `\tellmethedepthinthislineuptonow` (and nothing else) which would work.

Comment: there are also **big** problems with how fonts are used in math mode, from where do the various dimensions or symbols come, ..., but clearly if I go on I will start a flame war...

Comment: I might point out that Knuth himself has written a [paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=66416) (behind a paywall, unfortunately) on the design mistakes in TeX.

Comment: ..about the depth thing (or other more useful hooks into the paragraph breaking algorithm) I can see that it is necessary to avoid the risk of infinite loops; but there are safe actions such as deciding to increase the linespacing throughout the paragraph (or only for the line before, the current line, the next line) which have no impact on the line-breaking hence could have been allowed. `LuaTeX` as far as I have understood does address these issues.

Comment: Do you really want the question *and* the answer to appear here? I mean, it thereby probably becomes a test of knowing or not knowing tex.se...

Comment: @Daniel: For a certain case like David Carlisle's question, I think the output from the candidate is more than enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ask them to correct the typesetting of the twelve days of Christmas in `xii.tex` to replace `lords a leaping` by `lords-a-leaping` (and make @barabarabeeton happy at the same time).

Comment: Does it accommodate the maximum number of plain TeX concepts?

Comment: @Marienplatz no

Answer (score 3):

Pretend you are editing a journal with short articles, say 3–6 pages each, each page having one of the following layouts:

- *Title page,* upper-half of the page has a title and picture, then a full-width abstract and the article text is then split in two columns.
- *Normal page,* with text split in two columns, eventually insertions at the top.
- *Decorated page,* with text split in two columns and a figure in the middle of the page.

Here is an attempt to draw a picture of a decorated page, where X's stand for text and dots for the figure:

```
XXXXX XXXXX
XXXXX XXXXX
XXX ... XXX
XXX ... XXX
XXX ... XXX
XXXXX XXXXX
XXXXX XXXXX
```

Ask the person to devise an output routine for such a journal or tell him, he will be part of a team devising an output routine for such a journal.

Once you have listed the set of skills you want to test, you can devise questions and scenarios to get the maximum out of the interview.  From this setup you can choose to explore various skills like software organisation, macro programming,  paragraph breaking, box operations, math displays, alignment and multipass jobs…